# Getting error on image cropping / Converting UIImage to CGImage / Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, image, uiimage, crop, cgimage

I'm a little new to programming and I'm trying to capture a screenshot then crop it to a specific region.
I was able to come up with the code below, but it's giving me the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error, which usually doesn't tell you much. I tried to isolate snipets of the code to see where the error is coming from and it looks like it's from the CIImage to CGImage conversion.

I have already tried going from UIImage to CGImage directly, but I get the same error.

This is the screenshot capture code that calls the crop function.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

let itemToShare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

cropImage(itemToShare)
```

This is the crop function. The .cropping(to: is commented out because I wanted to make sure the error was not coming from the crop.

```
func cropImage(_ screenshot: UIImage) -> CGImage {

        let ciImage = CIImage(image: screenshot)

        let crop = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50)

        let cgImage = (ciImage as! CGImage)  //.cropping(to: crop)!

        return cgImage
}
```

I appreciate all the help as I have been researching this for a few days and all the answers on stack or on Apple dev forums lead the same way.

Daniel

Comment: If you look in the console (on a debug build), you should get more info, in a message like "Could not cast value of type `CIImage` to `CGImage`." And indeed, you can't cast a `CIImage` to a `CGImage`, because they're unrelated types. You're looking for something like [`CIImage.createCGImage(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437784-createcgimage)

Comment: I tried the create method and got a message that it has been ‘deprecated’ and Xcode suggested the downcasting. Also, tried from UIImage to CGImage, and got the same error. I’ll try to look at the console to see what it says.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CI API in particular, but the general point is still true. `CIImage` and `CGImage` are unrelated types, and you can't cast between them (just like how you can't do `"a string" as! Int`). You need to use some kind of CoreImage or CoreGraphics method to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found the solution, posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after further research I found the error was in trying to create a CGImage without a context.

So, a couple of lines solved it.

First, the UIImage gets converted to a CIImage with

```
let ciImage = CIImage(image: screenshot)
```

then the CIImage gets converted to a CGImage with a context

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage!, from: ciImage!.extent)
```

now, cgImage can be cropped with

```
let crop = CGRect(x: 0,
                  y: 0,
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200)
let cropedImage = cgImage!.cropping(to: crop)
```

and finally, the resulting cropped CGImage can be turned into a UIImage and returned by the function

```
return UIImage(cgImage: cropedImage!)
```

Apparently you can't go from a UIImage straight to CGImage.

Attention to sizes and scale as one uses points as reference and the other pixels... so you need to do some math figuring to get exact cropping positions for what you would like.